# Make one sprite follow another off centre, including rotation

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm working on a car drift game, which I want to make skid marks with using the pen.

I created a circle, radius 25 around the car that I am using as a reference for where the tires would be, and I need to get the tire sprite to follow the back end of car according to its rotation. I'm trying to adapt the formulas x'= xcosθ−ysinθ, y'= xsinθ+ycosθ but I don't know how to do it.

I set the initial x value as 0 and the y value as -25, but I know this is wrong because it doesn't stay the same when the car is moved and rotated.

Here is my project:
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/535410396/

Comment: I'm seeing skid marks on your scratch project....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that this has now been solved. I got th solution on the Scratch forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from a user of the Scratch Forums. For the x value:

```
CarX-25*sin(CarRotation)
```

For the y value:

```
CarY-25*cos(CarRotation)
```